# CouchbaseLite wait for pull replication to finish

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite

I have a CouchDB that I am connecting via CouchBaseLite 1.4. I am having trouble waiting for all documents to be pulled before continuing on with the application.

Currently I am achieving this in a very hacky way and I would like to fix it to be better in line with proper coding standards.

Current:

```
pull.setContinuous(false);
pull.start();

//Waits for pull replication to start pulling in data
while(!pull.isRunning());

//Waits for pull replication to finish.
while(!pull.getStatus().equals(Replication.ReplicationStatus.REPLICATION_STOPPED));

//Set continuous to true
pull.setContinuous(true);

//Start it again.
pull.start();
```

The reason I am doing this is I potentially have 2 documents in the DB that I need to wait for, if they are not present the desktop app goes into setup mode.

- Is there any way to wait for all documents to complete pulling
     without the hacky double `while`?
- Even better, lets assume I know the `_id`'s of the docs. Is there a way to wait until BOTH are pulled before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use change listeners.  To monitor replications, you want something like

```
// Replication.ChangeListener
@Override
public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
  if (changeEvent.getError() != null) {
    Throwable lastError = changeEvent.getError();
    // React to the error
    return;
  }

  if (changeEvent.getTransition() == null) return;

  ReplicationState dest = changeEvent.getTransition().getDestination();

  replicationActive = ((dest == ReplicationState.STOPPING || dest == ReplicationState.STOPPED) ? false : true);

  // Do something here if true
}
```

You could do something similar with a change listener on the database object to catch when the two specific documents have been replicated.

Since it sounds like you're expecting these docs to be in the database after initial setup somewhere else, another approach would be to do a one-shot replication to get those first documents, then start a continuous replication after it has finished.

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my issue, as a `changeListener` wouldn't stop my main thread from running. I went with your second suggestion, and used a one-shot replication to grab the two docs. It now runs noticeably quicker. Although I still used the double while, I'm only waiting for two docs so the pause is minimal and acceptable, even if the code is ugly.

Comment: Ah, yes, I usually think in non-blocking terms.  A couple of other thoughts: Pick up the main execution via a call in the callback, or put the thread to sleep and signal it from the callback?